# How to create this matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector such as

`A=[4;3;1;6]`

and I want to create a matrix with the elements below from `A`

`B=[6 5 4 3 2 1;4 3 2 1 0 0;3 2 1 0 0 0;1 0 0 0 0 0];`

How can I do this in MATLAB ? the number of columns equal to the max of A.

Comment: The question is unclear. is B storing indexes of elements in A (because A has only 4 elements and in maltab there is no 0 index). The relation  that you wish to get between A and B is unclear to me.

Comment: What's wrong with loops? Loops are very useful things. In this case a loop is probably the most logical thing to use.

Comment: Do you want the number of columns to be a fixed value, or equal to the max of `A`? Have you tried anything? Do you have any code?

Comment: I see that you have multiple questions with good answers, yet none of the answers are marked as accepted. [Accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) is the only way at your current reputation level that you can thank answerers for their time devoted to solve your problem. Whenever you find that an answer solves your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do this: one vectorized, and one in a loop.

```
A=[4;3;1;6];
B = max(bsxfun(@minus, sort(A, 'descend'), 0:(max(A)-1)), 0);
```

or

```
S = sort(A, 'descend');
m = numel(A); n = S(1);
C = zeros(m,n);
for k = 1:m
   C(k,1:S(k)) = S(k):-1:1;
end
```

Results:

```
B =

   6   5   4   3   2   1
   4   3   2   1   0   0
   3   2   1   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0
```